# No error message but stuck at Sending Request in POSTMAN

Tags: postman

I have used a simple POST API. It works in the development environment when there was a single data. But the Request didn't become successful.[Here is the Screenshot of my POSTMAN]
[image]

Comment: Was the request stuck forever, or timed out after some time? Try the "Send and download", you can find it by clicking on the triangle next to the send button

Comment: In API implementation, did you checked if API return back with proper response status and msg/body?

Comment: How long did you wait? You didn't receive any error logs?

Answer (score 2):

Clearing Cache and Reloading Worked well for me.

[A Pic Of Where to find clear cache and reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKOAd.png)

[image: screenshot]